# Backbone view not populating

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am passing a collection and a model to my view:

```
 popModel = new GenreModel({genre_name:'Pop',genre_id:'pop'});
 popView = new GenreView ({model:popModel,collection:new PopCol()});
```

This is the implementation of the View:

```
Backbone.View.extend ({
    className:'sect',

    initialize: function ()
    {
        context = this;
        this.collection.fetch ({
            success:function ()
            {
                context.render();
            }
        });     
    },

    render: function ()
    {
        console.log("hello");
        this.$el.html (_.template(view,this.model.toJSON()));
        this.collection.each (function (video) 
        {
            genreLi = new GenreLi ({model:video});
            this.$(this.model.genre_id).append (genreLi.el);
        },this);

        return this;
    },

});
```

My problem is that when I call console.log (popView.el) I am getting the following:

```
<div class="sect"></div>
hello
```

The view is not populating but when I call console.log (popView.render.el) I getting:

```
hello 
<div class=​"sect">​…​</div>​
hello
```

The View then renders properly.How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you give us a fiddle to work with?

Answer (score 1):

I Guess you are trying to show all the videos of same genre in a ul li list.
I think you are missing the '#' before id while getting the element.

```
render: function ()
{
    ...
    this.collection.each (function (video) 
    {
        genreLi = new GenreLi ({model:video});
        // if you have already defined elements by genre id and not within the view's el
        // This is not good as a view should attach new html into dom elements under it 
        $('#'+this.model.genre_id).append (genreLi.el);

        // if you have defined elements by genre id within in the view'w el then
        this.$el.find('#'+this.model.genre_id).append (genreLi.el);

    },this);

    return this;
},
```